# Scipy csr_matrix does not copy correctly

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am having some issues calculating from one csr_matrix and creating a new on from the results. In trying to track it down, I just did some simple code to copy the original matrix and the copy is not the same. I have tried it on very small matrices (as given in the documentation), but on a real world matrix (about 2.5M entries, all of which are non-zero), the results are bizarre. Here is the test code:

```
print type(X_ngrams)
tst = csr_matrix( (X_ngrams.data,X_ngrams.nonzero()))
print "Original:"
print "shape     ", X_ngrams.shape
r1,c1=X_ngrams.nonzero()
print "rows, cols", r1[:10],c1[:10]
print "indptr    ", X_ngrams.indptr[:10]
print "indices   ", X_ngrams.indices[:10]
print "data[:10] ", X_ngrams.data[:10]
#
print
print "Copy:"
print "shape     ", tst.shape
r2,c2=tst.nonzero()
print "rows, cols", r2[:10],c2[:10]
print "indptr    ", tst.indptr[:10]
print "indices   ", tst.indices[:10]
print "data[:10] ", tst.data[:10]
```

Here are the results:

```
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
Original:
shape      (2257, 202262)
rows, cols [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [ 69627  70494 168418 174006 157892     161787 146945 148354  51951  53422]
indptr     [   0  518 1247 3156 3634 4368 5594 6670 8540 9257]
indices    [ 69627  70494 168418 174006 157892 161787 146945 148354  51951  53422]
data[:10]  [ 2  1 23  1 35  1 11  1  8  1]

Copy:
shape      (2257, 202262)
rows, cols [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [1439 2461 2561 2683 2748 4279 6212 6275 6332 6611]
indptr     [   0  518 1247 3156 3634 4368 5594 6670 8540 9257]
indices    [1439 2461 2561 2683 2748 4279 6212 6275 6332 6611]
data[:10]  [20  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1]
```

Why is the structure of the copy different? The matrix I need to create should have exactly the same structure, just a different number in each position.

Comment: Did you notice that you mislabeled your output of the copy?  You print `tst.data[:10]` after the label `"indptr    "`.

Comment: Since we don't have the full code, I have to ask: are you sure `X_ngrams` is a `csr_matrix`?

Comment: Warren, thanks for catching the typos. I have updated the code. I also added the type of X_ngrams to show that it is, in fact, a csr_matrix

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate your problem with the data you give, but I suspect the problem lies with `X_ngrams` not being sorted, while the copy is sorted.  The sorting was performed by `nonzero`.

Compare the 2 `indices`.  Both are a small sample of the 500+ values in the first row:

```
indices    [ 69627  70494 168418 174006 157892 161787 146945 148354  51951  53422]
indices    [1439 2461 2561 2683 2748 4279 6212 6275 6332 6611]
```

The 2nd list is smaller, and sorted.  What's the value of `X_ngrams.has_sorted_indices`?

What you really need to compare is `nonzero` of both.

One solution is to sort `X_ngrams` first

```
 X._ngrams.sort_indices()  # sort in place
```

You might also consider using `M.copy()` or `M.tocsr(copy=True)`.  `M.sorted_indices()` returns a copy with sorted indicies.

This format:

```
sparse.csr_matrix((M.data, M.indices, M.indptr))
```

makes a copy using the same arrays a `M`. Or if you want them to be copies:

```
sparse.csr_matrix((M.data.copy(), M.indices.copy(), M.indptr.copy()))
```

Comment: Interesting. The value of X_ngrams.has_sorted_indices = 0.

Comment: Thank you. Sorting the indices on X_ngrams and then doing the copy based on the indices and indptrs seems to work. I am not really clear I understand why that is necessary, but I will use that approach.

My real goal is not actually to copy the matrix, but to perform an element-by-element evaluation that does not seem to be possible with the built-in sparse array operators. By doing what you suggest, I can make a modified copy of the original data and build a new matrix with exactly the same elements.

Thank you.